# Configure AWS Cloud9 to use Anaconda Python Environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, anaconda, aws-cloud9

I want AWS Cloud9 to use the Python version and specific packages from my Anaconda Python environment. How can I achieve this? Where should I look in the settings or configuration?

My current setup: I have an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu Linux, and I have configured AWS Cloud9 to work with the EC2 instance.

I have Anaconda installed on the EC2 instance, and I have created a conda Python3 environment to use, but Cloud9 always wants to use my Linux system's installed Python3 version.

Comment: I found a related question, with no answer unfortunately... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108586/aws-cloud9-python-virtual-environment-is-not-actually-activated-uses-system-wi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found something that forces AWS Cloud9 to use the Python3 version installed in my Anaconda environment on my AWS EC2 instance.

The instructions to create a custom AWS Cloud9 runner for Python are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-python.html):

```
{
    "cmd" : ["/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/ijackweb/bin/python3.6", "$file", "$args"],
    "info" : "Running $project_path$file_name...",
    "selector" : "source.py"
}
```

I just create a new runner and paste the above code in there, and Cloud9 runs my application with my Anaconda environment's version of Python3.

The only thing I don't understand about the above code is what the "selector": "source.py" line does.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing, I realised that my previous answer prevents you being able to use the debugger. Building on @Sean_Calgary 's answer (which is better than my original answer), you can edit one of the in-built python runners (again, just replacing the python call with the full path to the conda env's python path), like so:

```
    {
  "script": [
    "if [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
    "    /home/tg/miniconda/envs/env-name/bin/python -m ikp3db -ik_p=15471 -ik_cwd=$project_path \"$file\" $args",
    "else",
    "   /home/tg/miniconda/envs/env-name/bin/python \"$file\" $args",
    "fi",
    "checkExitCode() {",
    "    if [ $1 ] && [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
    "        /home/tg/miniconda/envs/env-name/bin/python -m ikp3db 2>&1 | grep -q 'No module' && echo '",
    "    To use python debugger install ikpdb by running: ",
    "        sudo yum update;",
    "        sudo yum install python36-devel;",
    "        sudo pip-3.6 install ikp3db;",
    "        '",
    "    fi",
    "   return $1",
    "}",
    "checkExitCode $?"
  ],
  "python_version": "python3",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "debugport": 15471,
  "$debugDefaultState": false,
  "debugger": "ikpdb",
  "selector": "^.*\\.(py)$",
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "$python_path"
  },
  "trackId": "Python3"
}
```

To do this, just click on 'runners' next to CWD in the bottom-right corner -> python3 -> edit runner -> save as 'env-name.run' in /.c9/runners (that save as should point you to the right directory by default).

**N.B.**

1. Replace `env-name` with the name of your environment throughout.
2. You will need the package for the debugger installed in your conda env. It's called `ikp3db`.
3. You may need to check the path to your conda envs executable python by activating the environment and running `which python` (his caught me out because my path ended in `/python`, not `/python3.6`, even though it's python 3.6 that's installed)

Comment: I am getting "AssertionError: SRE module mismatch" error when I run a file with my environment. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SinanGok did you install ikp3db into your conda environment? It sounds like you conda environment is lacking a python package that it needs..

Comment: I actually fixed that problem by updating conda with python=3.6. My custom runner, where I replaced the python path as you suggested above, did not work yesterday for some reason. But it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 'shell script' runner type. To do this you would:

1. create your conda env, with python3 and any packages etc you want in it. Call it `py3env`
2. create a directory to hold your runner scripts, something like `$HOME/c9_runner_scripts`
3. put a script in there called `py3env_runner.sh` runner with code like:

   `conda activate py3env
    python ~/c9/my_py3_script.py`
4. Then create a run configuration with the 'shell script' runner type and enter `c9_runner_scripts/py3env_runner.sh`

Answer (score -1):

for me, on centos 7 the only way to execute with my conda python v 3.9.4 was to add a conda activate line to my .bash_profile like this:

> conda activate /var/www/my_conda/python3.9

Then in Cloud 9 when I'm running my code under my conda python 3.9 env all is fine.

This is my simple python code which will print the current python version

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Best.